# Why does $\int_0^s \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x^2 dx$ not give the volume of a regular tetrahedron with side length $s$?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, volume

Suppose I want to find the volume of a regular tetrahedron with side length $s$. Intuitively, I thought we could sum over the areas of all equilateral triangles of side length $x$, where $0 \leq x \leq s$, and that should be the answer. Since the height of any equilateral triangle is $s\sqrt{3}/{2}$ we can compute
$$\int_0^s \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\cdot x\ dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}s^3.$$
but this gives the wrong formula for the volume.

I know another way to find the solution so I am not looking for that kind of an answer, but I am looking for an explanation as to why the above is incorrect. Does it not account for something geometrically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a variable along the side of the triangle, so the thickness of your infinitesimal slices is not $dx$. You have to multiply by the cosine of the angle between the side and the altitude, which is $\sqrt{2/3}$. So your final number is multiplied by that and you should get the right formula.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me realize the problem but I did not fully understand your answer. The angle you are referring to should be 30 degrees right? In which case the cosine of that angle is $1/2$. Also, how does multiplying by this angle allow us to geometrically interpret the integral as you mentioned?

Comment: You are slicing your tetrahedron with planes perpendicular to one of its altitudes (that is why your sections are equilateral triangles). Your slices are prisms with equilateral base and thickness $dh$, the separation between your planes. The ratio $dh/dx$ is the cosine of the angle between the altitude and the side. Using Pythagorean Theorem twice you can convince yourself that altitude=$\sqrt{2/3}$.side.